# After database migration, theme mods don't show

Tags: database, migration, get-theme-mod

My Wordpress installation has only one theme which is active.  The `wp_option` entry for it shows there are 31 theme mod entries.

```
a:31:{s:18:"custom_css_post_id";i:5248;s:30:"theme_settings_api_keys_google";s:39:"xxx.....etc..";s:28:"theme_settings_xxx";........etc...etc...etc....;s:11:"custom_logo";i:5810;}
```

however when I run `get_theme_mod( 'my_mod_x' ))` nothing comes is returned.
So too when I run on the command line: `wp theme mod get --all --allow-root`.  All I get is:

```
+--------------------+-------+
| key                | value |
+--------------------+-------+
| custom_css_post_id | 5248  |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Can anyone tell me what would cause WordPress to think there is only one theme mod when there is supposed to be many?

Comment: Is this a multisite installation?

Comment: and does your theme still have the same name/folder name as before?

Comment: This is a single-site installation.  The theme still has the same name/folder as before.  However, there is a suspicious looking line in the database migration `wp_option` table data:  `current_theme` is set to 'Twenty Seventeen/my-theme-folder-name'.  The server this was migrated from does have many themes stored on it.  But why should it matter once the correct theme is present and active on the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that one if the the serialized string lengths did not match its true string length.  One of the migration steps was to change the domain name in the database SQL file with:

`sed -i 's/old-domain-name/new-domain/g' db-dump.sql`

One of the theme mods was a string that contained the old domain name.  When it was changed to the new domain name, the length of the string was not adjusted to to match the new string length.  Therefore, WordPress was unable to properly read the theme mods.

Lesson: Be careful when doing a global find and replace on the db-dump.sql file!

Comment: A much better we to do find and replace is with the WordPress CLI, 
 Here is a good tutorial.  https://torquemag.io/2017/04/switch-domain-names-wp-cli/